# Are "old" questions/answers eligible for badges?

Tags: bug, badges

*This is a trivia question, the only reason I dare to bring this up is because we have entertained similar curiosities here on Meta about the functioning of MO.*

[An old accepted answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/73266/11260) of mine from 2011 received it's tenth upvote a few days ago. This should trigger a bronze and a silver badge, but none appeared. Just out of curiosity, I wonder: is this because old posts have a separate badge queue that only runs occasionally, is it because posts from before MO migrated to SE no longer participate in the badge circus, or is it just a random glitch?

Comment: I can imagine the badge calculations change in such a way that this question is ineligible, whereas the same question posted four years later might be eligible, for the badges.  If you provide more details as to what you expect and why, we can refine our speculations.  Gerhard "Iffy, This Whole Badge Business" Paseman, 2018.04.16.

Comment: well, the expected behaviour would have been the award of the "nice answer" badge and the "enlightened" badge (embarassing name, but that's what it's called)

Comment: OK. Although someone here may know, my guess is the trivia question is mostly independent of MathOverflow.  Gerhard "You're Nicely Enlightened Enough Already?" Paseman, 2018.04.16.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact you have received the [enlightened](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/36/enlightened?userid=11260) and [nice answer](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/45?userid=11260) badges for this post on July 18 2016.

You'll have to scroll a bit down or even go to next page. Here is screenshot from your page listing enlightened badges:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is screenshot from the page with your nice answer badges:

[image: Screenshot]

I can see an upvote from July 18 2016 on [your reputation tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11260/carlo-beenakker?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=17) but not [in the post's timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/73266/timeline).<sup>1</sup>

[image: Screenshot of the reputation tab]

To me the most plausible explanation to me seems to be that the user who upvoted your answer at the time has been since removed - that's why the upvote is no longer shown in the timeline. (Or the upvote was removed for some other reason...?) Maybe somebody will be able to investigate further based on the data provided here and possibly confirm whether this is indeed the case.

I will also explicitly point out that with the exception of [tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-badges/info), no badge is taken away, even if the criteria why it was awarded no longer hold. (Like in this instance removal of an upvote which lead to decrease of the answer score below the threshold.) For more details on this see: [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853) (The section "What can cause a badge to be lost/revoked/taken away after it is awarded?")

<sup>1</sup>To see how to get timeline for a specific post: [How to see questions time line?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24826)

Comment: brilliant, thank you very much for this detailed and authoritative answer!